# Red Pixels in Render

Tags: rendering, materials

in the last few days I have made one of my first environments in Blender.
I have played with the "new" geometry node and made a material that creates a snowy mountain.

My Problem: in the Render, I have these weird pixels (mostly red) ONLY on the mountain material. [image]
I'll link a Picture with the nodes of the material.[image]
Thanks for any help I will receive.

// One Problem could be the combination of the displacement textures, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the noodle going into *Subsurface* on the bottom *Principled BSDF*.

Comment: Oh!..... Thank you

Comment: I can see that it is some snow texture with translucent texture so it wanted to go into subsurface... it can go to subsurface but by default, subsurface gives you a red tone(like human skin)... you need to manually change values in subsurface radius (it uses RGB values so you should go for something like 0.1/0.2/0.8, I don't know it's just my guess, those information are online) to match what snow should be or use it some different way